# Cassandra OperationTimeOut when using truncate, drop, delete and create index etc

Tags: cassandra, database, nosql

My table has about 190,000 rows now, and it keep increasing. I need to truncate it and reload from backup everyday. But when executing `truncate`, `drop`, and `delete`, it shows `OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=xxx.xxx.xx.xx`. Is there any method to solve this?

A couple of days ago, I increased `timeout` in config file and it worked. But it does not work anymore when my table has more rows. Please tell me better methods to fix this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I finally figure it out by changing `auto_snapshot` to `false` in cassandra.yaml. But it may make the data unsafety. Looking forward to better solutions.

Comment: Snapshots in general are created using hardlinks to the (already) immutable sstables. Maybe what's slowing you down is the flushing operation preceding the snapshots themselves. Once disabled you'll still have to wait the flush activity, AND the file deletion operation, what you'll save is probably only space.

Comment: What you say makes sense. However it does work even though i cannot explain why. Is there the probability that taking snapshot is a time-consuming procedure?

Comment: Snapshots are fast IMHO, flushes can slow down things considerably. And compactions could come after flushes, so slow down again.

Comment: The timeout exception comes up again. This may show snapshot is not the reason that slows me down. @xmas79

Comment: Now, I must increase `timeout` day and day. :-(

Comment: You should post your schema and your queries.

Comment: I use `truncate` everyday, and then restore the table from backup.     A couple days ago, I found what solves the `OperationTimeout`problem temporarily is not increasing timeout or turning off auto-snapshot but restarting casandra server. Since every time I modified the config file and then restarted cassandra server, I was misled all the time.    I am still confused what make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Increase your timeout again. Or issue the query a few more times, they will eventually succeed. The "schema modification" queries are known to be "slow", and they can be slower when there's some compaction activity in progress.

Comment: Increasing timeout is a solution. But I need to do this frequently with the increasing of rows.Thanks.

Comment: @ethan: I think it depends more on how many tables do you have than on how many rows.

Comment: The number of my table is constant. And under the same configuration, the table with less rows works fine, but table with more rows shows timeout. Would you please explain why it depends on the number of table?

Comment: I experienced similar issues. Schemas with 20 CFs were deleted in under 2 seconds. Schemas with 260 CFs were deleted in... buh... I run the command and went back there a few minutes later. I think the problem with the number of CFs is that they all cause flushes when you drop a schema, and each flush is a potential compaction.I don't clearly know how C* manages to drop a table if there's an active compaction running, but I suspected it waits the schema to be *idle* before dropping it,so flushes and compaction are your enemies,and more rows means potential longer compactions.